# JsonString to Json using jolt

Tags: jolt

I have a Json where there is a key with a value which is a JsonString.
I want to convert it to Json
input:

```
 {
        "SEARCH_RESULT": "{ \"requestId\": \"203680\", \"responseData\": [ { \"searchKey\": \"cardNumber\", \"data\": [ { \"firstName\": \"Martin\", \"lastName\": \"Garry\" }, { \"firstName\": \"Martin\", \"lastName\": \"Garry\"}, { \"firstName\": \"Martin\", \"lastName\": \"Garry\",  } ] } ] }"
    }
```

here the value of the SEARCH_RESULT is a valid Json String.
I want to convert this to Json

```
{
    "SEARCH_RESULT": { "requestId": "203680", "responseData": [ { "searchKey": "cardNumber", "data": [ { "firstName": "Martin", "lastName": "Garry" }, { "firstName": "Martin", "lastName": "Garry"}, { "firstName": "Martin", "lastName": "Garry",  } ] } ] }
}
```

I tried to see if I can use Modify_Beta but I couldn't find any function to do that.

Comment: Hi Anderson. This issue might be handled through Jolt but through employing some redundant hardcodes. I suppose some other tool, library or method might be more helpful I believe.